# Why does setting the property as a constant work in mongo mongoose but not just the method getting the value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update some value in my database using python and mongoose (mongo wrapper library). The value I am trying to update is contained in an array (filename).

Full method

```
module.exports.updateCampground = async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const campground = await Campground.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { ...req.body.campground });
    const imgs = req.files.map(f => ({ url: f.path, filename: f.filename }));
    campground.images.push(...imgs);
    await campground.save();
    if (req.body.deleteImages) {
        for (let filename of req.body.deleteImages) {
            //logs cloudinary conataining uploader, still uploader is undefined
            console.log(cloudinary,cloudinary.uploader); 
            await cloudinary.uploader.destroy(filename);
        }
        await campground.updateOne({ $pull: { images: { filename: { $in: req.body.deleteImages } } } })
    }
    req.flash('success', 'Successfully updated campground!');
    res.redirect(`/campgrounds/${campground._id}`)
};
```

This works

```
const deleteImg = req.body.deleteImages
await campground.updateOne({ $pull: { images: { filename: { $in: deleteImg } } } })
```

and removes the item however when I do just this it doesn't

```
await campground.updateOne({ $pull: { images: { filename: { $in: req.body.deleteImages } } } })
```

Why do I need the const to work? Is it some javascript thing?

Comment: It really shouldn't matter. The query will execute successfully as long as it has the right input provided.

Comment: you may have oversimplified the reproduction of problem. deleteImg should be the same array as req.body.deleteImages (reference wise).  following is speculation: so maybe you assigned a new array to req.body.deleteImages before your update (which could explain why it works in first case (since deleteImg "not touched") and why not in the later (req.body.deleteImages touched after deleteImg and before update)

Comment: @TheWhiteFang That's what I thought too but it it works with the constant.

Comment: @grodzi There should be nothing assigned or anything overwriting req.body.deleteImages

Comment: try doing basic debugging. Like logging the `req.body.deleteImages` before executing the query, making sure that the values you are passing actually exists in db in each case and compare the results. I think what @grodzi said is accurate or the issue might be something similar.

Comment: @TheWhiteFang tried logging the values and they are the same. I added the whole body of code to the question as well

Comment: can you add the `console.log`s in the code and the output they are giving. It would be helpful if you could send the body of the request you are sending from frontend.